# React - hopefully simple formatting of a link

Tags: reactjs, forms, href

I have a form, in react, using react-bootstrap. I want to present an alert with the terms of service from a link next to the radio button.

This is my code:

```
          <Form.Row>
            {["radio"].map((type) => (
              <div key={`default-${type}`} className="mb-3">
                <Form.Check type={type} checked={false} id={`default-${type}`} value="1" onChange={formik.handleChange} onBlur={formik.handleBlur} label="I accept the"></Form.Check>
                <Link onClick={TosAlert}>{"Terms of Service"}</Link>
              </div>
            ))}
          </Form.Row>
```

[checkbox renders like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk1oE.jpg)

It's a small thing but, can anyone help me get it on the same row?

Comment: try the css `display` property on `mb-3` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending to label a react node instead of a string

```js
<Form.Row>
            {["radio"].map((type) => (
              <div key={`default-${type}`} className="mb-3">
                <Form.Check 
                type={type} 
                checked={false} 
                id={`default-${type}`} 
                value="1" 
                onChange={formik.handleChange} 
                onBlur={formik.handleBlur} 
                label={<>I accept the <Link onClick={TosAlert}>Terms of Service</Link></>}
                </Form.Check>
              </div>
            ))}
          </Form.Row>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been fiddling with it for ages. I do other things and then come back to it, never getting it quite right. That was perfect. Just needed an additional > before the closing </Form.Check>